# MYSQL SELECT query doesn't work in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I run the code below it does work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `be_22122020` WHERE 1";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "id: " . $row["code"]. " - Name: " . $row["airport_name"]. " " . $row["country_code"]."<br>";
}
```

But when I change the MYSQL query into the code below the pages shows an

> **AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool**

```
$sql = "SELECT `code`, `airport_name`, `country_code` FROM `be_22122020` WHERE code = 
\'JFK\'";
```

The MYSQL query is copied from phpMyAdmin and is should work. How can I fix this error so it echo's the correct values?

Comment: Please check for the error that caused the result to be a bool. Follow advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param

Comment: There is no need to escape single quotes when they're inside double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

I think your query is wrong.
Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM be_22122020 WHERE code = 'JFK'";
```

Comment: Thanks, did the trick.

Comment: When you are selecting an specific row you need to add WHERE clause = value like in this case you want to select all rows with code 'JFK' you can also add limit with LIMIT 5.